# Choose location of compiled file

Tags: python, python-3.x, compilation, python-3.5, bytecode

So I have a program that generates the bytecode of a python file. In this case i want to import statements from the bytecode(.pyc) file. I believe the file has to be in a parent folder so lets just say I want the file once compiled to be stored at /root/users/folder. But the code here only allows me just to compile it and store it into the current folder.

## Code:

```
from py_compile import compile as bytecode

bytecode(file='file.py')
```

Now I know a could just just move the file using another function but is their another way to store it specifically like how modules are stored in /root/users/__pycache__ when it is imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`py_compile.compile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/py_compile.html#py_compile.compile) accepts an optional parameter `cfile`:

```
import py_compile

py_compile.compile('file.py', cfile='/path/where-you-want-to-save/file.py')
```

Comment: I tried the following  before but I entered a directory path instead of a file path and thought it was for something else thanks.